# Slim 4 error handling not catching base Exception

Tags: php, error-handling, slim-4

For some reason, my Slim 4 application error handler did not catch  errors  which can be caught by `\Exception` and I see `502 bad gateway` error in the browser , here is my `ErrorMiddleware` configuration (I'm using PHP-DI to configure it ):

```
   $definitions[ErrorMiddleware::class] = static function(ContainerInterface $container): ErrorMiddleware {
            $middleware = new ErrorMiddleware(
                $container->get(CallableResolverInterface::class),
                $container->get(ResponseFactoryInterface::class),
                (bool)$container->get(Config::class)->get('main.debug'), //false or true
                true,
                true
            );
            $middleware->setErrorHandler(HttpNotFoundException::class, $container->get(NotFoundHandler::class));


            return $middleware;
        };
```

I tried to add handler to handle 500 error like this `$middleware->setErrorHandler(HttpInternalServerErrorException::class, $container->get(NotFoundHandler::class) );`

but it's not working and I still see `502 bad gateway` until I surround all controller action with `try/catch(\Exception $e)`.

Do I need to add some other error handlers??  It's not clear for me how to correctly setup up handling in a slim 4 application.

**Updated:**  I found that slim `ErrorMiddleware` by default catching slim `HttpException` which is extending `Exception`, but why not direclty `Exception` or even `Throwable` to gracefully exit application with nice error page

Answer (score 1):

Okay it's my bad, adn everithing is fine with a slim, it's failing in the 'log_error()' fucntion as `ErrorMiddlware` is configured to log the error, but I did not install and configure `Monolog` yet, so it write logs to `php-fpm` logs and `nginx` alongside throwing 502 error